# A problem regarding the definition of Uniform-continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

We know the definition of Uniform-continuity is

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and  $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$$\forall \epsilon>0\ (\exists \delta>0\ (|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon) )$$
then f is uniformly continuous on A.

If we consider the statement: Given $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\forall \delta>0\ (\exists \epsilon>0\ (|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon) )$$

Does this statement also hold for uniformly continuous functions defined on $A$?

Comment: Every bounded function (even those with no point of continuity) satisfy this condition.

Comment: Thank you. If I take $f(x)=x$, this function also has this property, right? I am searching for a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter implication follows purely logically from the first.

That implies, yes, the property is valid for all uniform continuous functions.

So for non uniform-continuous functions:
A counter example is $\mathbb R - \{0\}\ni x \mapsto 1/x$ .
Assume there is such a $\delta$, then set $x=-\delta/2$, $y=\delta/2$
Then $d(x,y)=\delta$, but $d(f(x),f(y))$ is not bounded for $\delta$ arbitrarily small

Comment: How can we conclude the second statement using the first? Can you please explain? I could not understand how it happens.

Comment: Since for  $\epsilon=1$ there exists $\delta>0$ s.th the function varies at most $1$ within $x,y$ varying $\delta$. Then for points $x,y$ with distance $|x-y|=D$ , the function varies at most $\lceil D/\delta \rceil=:\epsilon\prime$
,
Use $D,\epsilon\prime$ in the second statement